# i install laravel in mac os but i have error Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I installed Laravel in my MAC, but I have a problem when I start the install

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.6.21)
    - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.6.21): Loading from cache
      Created project in laravel
      @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
      Loading composer repositories with package information
      Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
      Package operations: 70 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
   - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.5.0): Downloading (100%)

[ErrorException]

 copy(/Users/mohammadreza/.composer/cache/files/vlucas/phpdotenv/860e02c1487d4eaac63d29a77c5fa31c2739df62.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Please help me

Comment: Use youtube tutorial for dummies. I am not kidding, but you should learn how to set this up properly by doing research.

Comment: I also agree with Ronnie.  How to do a proper installation should be easily followed through a guide or tutorial.  You can even google for the specific error you got on common problems like this.  Did you research guides or tutorials first?

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow. :)  Make sure to upvote answers that help you with your problem and accept correct answers.

Comment: Yes, I've gone all the way. I've done everything. I've even opened the open access to the terminal, but I do not know why it's not right.

Answer (score 0):

"The failed to open stream: Permission denied" part is the key part.  It's telling you it couldn't open a file stream because it doesn't have permissions to do so.  This would indicate the user executing PHP doesn't have required file permissions.  If you are running PHP from within another framework (such as Apache) then you need to look there to see what user is being used to run PHP.  If you're running PHP directly yourself, then you need to see what user you're running it at as.  Then you need to make sure that user has permissions to do the operation.

That's about the best answer I can give without specifics of your system architecture and installation settings.
NOTE:  I've never used laravel before.  I'm just telling you what the error is indicating.

Comment: NOTE:  I see you're a new user.  Make sure to accept this answer if you feel it's the correct one.  Also upvote it if it helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Has a relationship with a new user?
My dear friend, my problem is only on a Mac that was already installed, but now I do not know the problem

Comment: tnq for  answer 
It's ok, but I checked it out, it's okay

Answer (score 0):

You can try sudo composer global require "laravel/installer"
If that still not works consider create your laravel project via 
Via Composer Create-Project, e.g.
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel your-project-name

For the details installation please refer
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you my friend
I have trouble in the composer
I can not update, I do not have anything else, and in php artisan server project, I find that there is a problem with autoload line 17, which is related to installing composer and doing all the paths but failed.